# C# - Marshall by value problem!

Tags: c#, clr, marshalling, appdomain, value-objects

Here is the thing, I have a problem creating a new object using the remote mechanism "marshal by value".

Here is my class:

```
  [Serializable]
    internal class Empleado_MBV
    {
        public Empleado_MBV()
        {
            Id = 123456789;
            Nombres = "NotEntry";
            Apellidos = "NotEntry";
            FechaNacimiento = DateTime.MinValue;
            Direccion = "NotEntry";
            Metapreferencias = "NotEntry";
        }

        private List<Multas> _multas;

        internal List<Multas> Multas
        {
            get { return _multas; }
            set { _multas = value; }
        }

        private int _id;

        public int Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }
        private string _nombres;

        public string Nombres
        {
            get { return _nombres; }
            set { _nombres = value; }
        }
        private string _apellidos;

        public string Apellidos
        {
            get { return _apellidos; }
            set { _apellidos = value; }
        }
        private DateTime _FecNac;

        public DateTime FechaNacimiento
        {
            get { return _FecNac; }
            set { _FecNac = value; }
        }
        private string _direccion;

        public string Direccion
        {
            get { return _direccion; }
            set { _direccion = value; }
        }
        private string _metapreferencias;

        public string Metapreferencias
        {
            get { return _metapreferencias; }
            set { _metapreferencias = value; }
        }

        public string _AppDomainHost
        {
            get { return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.ToString(); }
        }
    }
```

But when I try to create an object in another "appdomain", the property "_AppDomainHost" of "Empleado" does not show the "appdomain" I had created, but show the "appdomain" by default. Some ideas?

```
AppDomain ad1 = AppDomain.CreateDomain("NewAppDomain");
        //Crear new object in my new AD.
        Empleado_MBV mbv_emp =      (Empleado_MBV)ad1.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap("DEMO_MBV_MBR.exe", "DEMO_MBV_MBR.Empleado_MBV");

        Console.WriteLine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("MBV : {0}",mbv_emp._AppDomainHost.ToString());

        Console.ReadLine();
```

**Result:**

DEMO_MBV_MBR.vshost.exe

MBV : DEMO_MBV_MBR.vshost.exe

**The result that I want:**

DEMO_MBV_MBR.vshost.exe

MBV : NewAppDomain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store `AppDomain` in `Empleado_MBV`'s constructor.

What you are doing right now is displaying current `AppDomain` using its `Current` static property. It will return the `AppDomain` where current code is being executed.

### Example:

```
private string _appDomainHost;
public string _AppDomainHost
{
    get { return _appDomainHost; }
}
```

and in constructor:

```
_appDomainHost = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.ToString();
```